# How to create Jar file from Maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, executable-jar

I have a Maven project, but I am not familiar to Maven. I wanted to create an executable JAR file from this Maven project to use it in another project by eclipse. How can I do this?

Comment: Follow this post:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Answer (score 34):

To build jar From Eclipse, Right click on your maven project name then

> Run as > Maven install

Answer (score 12):

Right click maven project,

choose `Run As-> Maven Build ....`

Type **package** in the **Goals** box.

Click Run.

Comment: Yes, this helped me actually. Earlier I was trying the arguments `maven package` and `mvn package` which didn't work to me. Tried just `package` and it created a jar under the folder `target` with all supported maven jars into it.

Answer (score 4):

Command line approach:

In the root of the project (the maven project), should be a pom.xml. Go to that root and run *mvn package*. If this is correct, there should be a new folder with the name *target* in the root of the project. Inside this folder there should be the jar file.

Comment: How do we 'run mvn package' here? :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you have to remember about security in Java. Many jars would not work in fatjars, if they got included in other projects (for example bouncycastle).

If you are doing a simple executable jar that has no libs in it, and requires all of them on classpath, default build (when packageing tag is set to jar) would be ok, and just require a proper manifest.

If you need all libs inside (fatjar), you need to configure it yourself.

There are several plugins for it, for example `maven-shade-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.INF</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>my.package.MainClass</Main-Class>
                            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>fat</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add following into `pom.xml` file and Run as `Maven Install`. This worked for me.

**pom.xml**

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>

 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

<build>
    <plugins>

    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.pohan.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    </plugins>


</build>
```

Now Run as `Maven Install`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want with the **terminal** to do it type

```
 mvn package
```

and a line before "BUILD SUCCESS" the directory of the

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install maven - https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Goto your project in eclipse
Run -> Maven install